shardingDataSource bean not being created
When I was using spring2.5, my setup was as follows:
To read configurations:
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "file:/etc/appconf/project/sharding/app-rule.properties"})
public class AppConfigProperties {
}

Configurations from file:
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.local00.type=com.local.MySQLDataSource
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.local00.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.local00.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/local00
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.local00.username=app_devuser
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.local00.password=######
spring.shardingsphere.datasource.local00.poolName=local00

shardingDataSource Bean:
@Data
@Component("shardingDataSource")
@Configuration
public class MySQLDataSource extends HikariDataSource {
    private Map<String, String> config;
    public void addConfig(String key, String value) {
        if (config==null){
            config = new HashMap<>();
        }
        config.put(key, value);

    }
}

Now, when earlier I called this function:
DataSource value = context.getBean("shardingDataSource", DataSource.class);
I got this output as value of value, among other things:
{dataSourceMap: {"local00": MySqlDataSource}}
But now after upgrading to spring 3.1.2, dataSourceMap is not being populated. As a result healthcheck is failing for the application since it couldn't find dataSource configuration
I expect the db queries to work as before. Thanks

Basically after upgrading to spring3.1.2, shardingproxy is not connecting to databases
<dependency>                 <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>                 <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>                 <version>8.0.33</version>             </dependency>             <dependency>                 <groupId>org.apache.shardingsphere</groupId>                 <artifactId>sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>                 <version>4.1.1</version>             </dependency>

Finally resolved this error:
Created a folder META-INF/spring
File Name: src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports
With Value: org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.SpringBootConfiguration
This resolved the error
